# ¿Como funciona Soket Push HTTP?

Tags: http, socket, push-notification, push

Recientemente se me pidió que reciba peticiones Socket TCP/IP y conteste por medio de un servidor socket que desarrollé en PHP. Ahora me avisan que van a enviarme mensajes con datos por socket, pero va a ser HTTP y utilizando el método PUSH.

1 - ¿Debo agregarle algo a mi servidor socket para que atienda HTTP?

2 - ¿Debo desarrollar otro servidor con características distintas?

3 - ¿En que influye que se utilice el método PUSH?

4 - ¿WebSocket me soluciona el problema?

Cualquier explicación al respecto Socket, HTTP, PUSH será bienvenida.

Gracias por su atención, es mi primer post, espero haber hecho bien las preguntas.

Comment: Creo que hacer algo con cockets _crudos_ para servir peticiones HTTP es como reinventar la rueda. Suena a que tienes que hacer un script PHP que vas a montar en un servidor WEB y que va a recibir peticiones PUSH.

Comment: Mucha gracias por tu respuesta:

Puedo interpretar que tu respuesta asiente que debo utilizar websocket para recibir las notificaciones push?

Comment: Nope.... yo entiendo que es una aplicación PHP montada en un servidor web.... _normal_, lo que hace el 90% de las aplicaciones hechas en PHP.... solo que tienes que verificar que las peticiones sean PUSH en el script y no de otros métodos.

Comment: OK. entonces podría resolverlo desde mi framework Laravel? tengo que recibirlo e identificar que es PUSH y procesar el json que me envía en este caso?

Comment: No se como se hacen las cosas en laravel pero en un script php _normal_ verificas `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` para saber si es PUSH... y tendrías que procesar lo que te llegue... ya esos son detalles. Se recibe el body como en un POST? Pues lo que recibas lo parseas como un json y a partir de ahí te diviertes.

Comment: Bueno tiene bastante sentido lo que me dices. El problema que encontré es que no existe entre los REQUEST_METHOD el metodo push, de hecho para estar seguro abri POSTMAN y no encontre PUSH. Igual parece bastante sensato lo que propones.

Comment: Es cierto; https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods. Estás seguro de que es `HTTP PUSH`?

Comment: Bueno, realmente me has ayudado, se trató de un error lingüístico de la persona encargada de comunicar los requisitos. Han utilizado el termino PUSH para indicar que ellos solo van a enviar request sin esperar una respuesta, pero es simple http. Perdón por haber ocupado el tiempo de tu parte y no verificar primero con la persona encargada de pedir los requisitos.
Agradezco muchísimo tu aporte, igualmente el $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] me sirvió para poder definir los metodos por los que llegarían los envíos.